# Why won't trello REST API return an oauth token during authorization?

Tags: api, authentication, authorization, trello

This is the URL I'm using to get oauth token https://trello.com/1/authorize?expiration=never&name=Dashboard&scope=read&response_type=token&key={{API_KEY}}&return_url=https%3A%2F%2F{{PAGE_HOST}}%2Foauth2callback%3Fstate={{DASHBOARD_DWID}}.

I'm able to bring up Trello authentication window and when I click "allow" button I'm redirected to URL given in return_url. I am able to get the {{DASHBOARD_DWID}} from this URL but there is no oauth token anywhere. Am I doing something wrong or why am I not seeing this token anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Trello actually returns the access token attached as the anchor tag in the URL. It would look something like https://{{PAGE_HOST}}/oauth2callback?state={{DASHBOARD_DWID}}#token={{TOKEN}}. Since I'm receiving this response on the server I didn't see this anchor tag anywhere as only the browser see's this value by default.